# Need help understanding this JS function code

Tags: javascript

I am new and learning JavaScript. I am learning about the concepts of helper functions and can't see to grasp to why this code does not produce a number value.

```js
function numOfAdults(parents) {
  parents *= 10;
  return parents;
}

function numOfChildren(children) {
  children = numOfAdults() * 5;
  return children;
}
console.log(numOfAdults(2));
console.log(numOfChildren());
```

I expected the result of `numOfChildren();` to be `100` but instead got `NaN.`

Comment: `numOfAdults()` takes an argument `parents`, you need to pass this argument when you use it in `numOfChildren()`

Comment: Also, the `children` argument for `numOfChildren()` is totally redundant

Answer (score 1):

The actual *why*:

```
function numOfAdults(parents) {
  console.log(parents); // undefined
  console.log(parents * 10); // NaN
}
numOfAdults();
```

Calling the function without arguments results in its parameters being *undefined*.

Using *undefined* in a calculation will generally produce *NaN* (meaning: *Not a Number*). Furthermore, **NaN propagates**, in that using NaN in a calculation will in turn yield NaN.

So you can see how you accidentally used an undefined value, got NaN, which propagated all the way through `numOfChildren` to your final `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

`numOfAdults` dont get any value passed to it. You must pass a value if you dont want it to return `NaN`. Since I dont know what value you want I added the dummy value of "5" in the following example:

```js
function numOfAdults(parents) {
  parents *= 10;
  return parents;
}

function numOfChildren(children) {
  number = 5; //Get the "parents" value, somehow
  children = numOfAdults(number) * 5; //Pass it to numOfAdults
  return children;
}
console.log(numOfAdults(2));
console.log(numOfChildren());
```

Comment: Since OP's question is fundamentally _"why doesn't this work"_, this answer would be better with some sort of description of the problem as opposed to just code

Comment: The explanation is commented in the code snippet @Phil

Comment: No, it is not. Your two comments do not describe the problem or why this answer provides a solution. Downvote isn't from me but you could easily improve this answer

Comment: The problem here is that numOfAdults dont get any value passed to it so I tell in my example that you should pass a value. Since I dont know what the OP wants I added the dummy value of "5". @Phil

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you aren't passing an argument to `numOfAdults`, therefore the  return value will be `undefined`. The correct code should look like this:

```js
function numOfAdults(parents) {
  parents *= 10;
  return parents;
}

function numOfChildren(children) {
  children = numOfAdults(children) * 5;
  return children;
}
console.log(numOfAdults(2));
```

You could improve your code by checking that the argument passed is valid:

```js
function numOfAdults(parents) {
  if (parents === undefined) {
    parents = 1; //1 parent by default
  }
  parents *= 10;
  return parents;
}

function numOfChildren(children) {
  children = numOfAdults(children) * 5;
  return children;
}

console.log(numOfAdults());
console.log(numOfChildren());
```

Similarly (if you're using ES6), you can set a [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) that will be used if none is passed by the calling code:

```js
function numOfAdults(parents = 1) { //1 parent by default
  parents *= 10;
  return parents;
}

function numOfChildren(children) {
  children = numOfAdults(children) * 5;
  return children;
}

console.log(numOfAdults());
console.log(numOfChildren());
```